# Issue in Uploading a file to Data extension in Exact target

Tags: dataextensions, marketing-cloud

I am trying insert a list of users to a newly created DataExtension but I am getting Upload error every time i try to import a file.I have checked all field and they are correct.But I can able to insert records through API.Below is the error message

[image: This is the error I am getting when I import a new file]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you close file before you tried to upload it?

Comment: Yes I closed the file before uploading it.Do i need anyother permissions?

Comment: Try doing a SAVE As with another name and check..
Also, make all fields in your data extension as Nullable.. that might help ..

Comment: Please post a sample of your CSV file and the schema of your target data extension.

Comment: @Maneesh i tried saving file in different name but it doesn't help.And there are only two fields one in Nullable and one is primary key.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs i have attached the images of schema and CSV file

Comment: For once, can you can make birthdate a text field and then try ?? I want to rule out the date format thing

Comment: I tried inserting records without that field and that field is nullable but i face the same error.Even i tried a dataextension with a single field but i face same error.

Comment: Do you have at least one FTP user created for your account?